# Получить из Map все entry ключ которых входит в коллекцию или массив

Tags: map, java-stream

Имеется массив значений

```
String [] str={ ONE, TWO, THREE };
```

и

```
Map <String, String> map.
```

Можно ли используя Stream API получить все entry из Map, ключ которых входит в данный массив?

Answer (score 2):

```
String [] strings = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE" };
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = Arrays.stream(strings)
            .filter(map::containsKey)
            .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, map.get(s)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**UPD.**

```
Map<String, String> filtered = Arrays.stream(strings)
            .filter(map::containsKey)
            .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, map.get(s)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,я не совсем верно выразился. Имел в виду получить из текущей мапы новую мапу, содержащую только те ентри в которых ключ совпадает с данными в массиве. То есть на выходе должен быть не List<Map.Entry<String, String>> а Map <String,String>

Comment: @Heineken, собственно, просто нужно поменять `Collector`, обновил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Стадии `map` и `collect` можно совместить и написать код проще: `Stream.of(str).filter(map::containsKey).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), map::get))`